# I am getting this error: The prop value with an expression type of Chain Expression could not be resolved. Please file is Failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Error:
./src/components/Main.jsx 26:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (26:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
|   var turncateString = function turncateString(str, num) {

> ```
> if (str?.length > num) {
> ```

|       return str.slice(0, num) + '....';
|     } else {

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import requests from "../Requests";
import axios from "axios";

const Main = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  const movie = movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)];

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(requests.requestPopular).then((response) => {
      setMovies(response.data.results);
    });
  }, []);
  // console.log(movie)
  const turncateString = (str, num) => {
    if (str?.length > num) {
      return str.slice(0, num) + "....";
    } else {
      return str;
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-[550px] text-white">
      <div className="w-full h-full">
        <div className="absolute w-full h-[550px] bg-gradient-to-r from-black"></div>
        <img
          className="w-full h-full object-cover"
          src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie?.backdrop_path}`}
          alt={movie?.title}
        />
        <div className="absolute w-full top-[40%] p-4 md:p-8">
          <h1 className="text-3xl md:text-5xl font-bold">{movie?.title}</h1>
          <div className="my-4">
            <button className="border bg-gray-300 text-black border-gray-300 py-2 px-5">
              Play
            </button>
            <button className="border text-gray-300  border-gray-300 py-2 px-5 ml-4">
              Watch Later
            </button>
          </div>
          <p className="text-gray-400 text-sm">
            Released: {movie?.release_date}
          </p>
          <p className="w-full md:max-w-[70%] lg:max-w-[50%] xl:max-w-[35%] text-gray-200">
            {turncateString(movie?.overview, 150)}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;

    enter code here
```

Comment: This is not a React issue, it's an eslint issue. See here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19940

I was able to run mock code similar to yours just fine, so it's an issue with either your eslint package(s) or version(s).